# Python 2 vs 3 raw bytes output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, types

I have the following code

```
import os
unk2 = os.urandom(10)
totlen = len("lol1") + len("lol2")
ownershipsectionwithsig = "random1" + "random2"
ticket = list(unk2) + list(ownershipsectionwithsig)
ticket = "".join(map(str, ticket))


print(ticket)
```

the code is for something i was testing related to RNG.

In python 2 it prints the following `?zoռv3L??random1random2`

However in python 3 it prints  `245148103178837822864207104random1random2`

For some reason python 3 doesn't show the raw byte output like python 2 does, it converts it into something. How would i make change my code so python 3 outputs the code the way python 2 does it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2 `bytes` are a sequence of string characters, so converting it into a list by calling `list(unk2)` turns it into a list of single-character strings:

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> unk2 = os.urandom(10)
>>> list(unk2)
['[', '\x12', '\xfa', '\x98', '\x87', '\x1e', '\n', '\xd1', '\xe2', '\x17']
```

In Python 3 `bytes` are a sequence of 8-bit integers, so converting it into a list by calling `list(unk2)` turns it into a list of integers, and by mapping each integer into a string and joining them together you get the long sequence of digits in the end:

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> unk2 = os.urandom(10)
>>> list(unk2)
[65, 77, 240, 11, 233, 106, 204, 69, 171, 214]
```

If you want to make Python 3 output the random byte sequence as a string like you do in Python 2 you can convert `bytes` into a string with the `bytes.decode` method instead:

```
unk2 = os.urandom(10).decode('latin-1')
```

Comment: im not sure what to do then

Comment: Okay thank you, however i don't like to just use answers without knowing why something works, so why does the decoder need latin-1 and not utf-8?

Comment: `latin-1` is the standard 8-bit character encoding, making it suitable for outputting string representation of bytes. `utf-8` is an encoding that ranges from 1 to 3 bytes, depending on the the 8th bit of the first byte, while the rest of the bytes also have to follow specific ranges, so chances are that the randomly generated bytes from `os.urandom` will fail to decode as `utf-8`.

Comment: @EmilB: Raw random bytes are almost never valid UTF-8 (UTF-8 is self-checking). Latin-1 is an encoding that (on Python at least) maps byte values 0 through 255 to the equivalent Unicode ordinals 0 through 255. So it always succeeds, and it's the most natural mapping from raw bytes to a string you're likely to get. That said, some of those bytes won't be printable (ASCII itself includes a ton of non-printable characters, and latin-1 is a superset of ASCII), so it's not a great idea. If you want to print raw bytes, printing them as hex or base64 encoded is usually the way to go.